# Recursive looping through components not working in VB

Tags: vb.net, loops, recursion

I'm trying to recursively loop through the components in a window, but it never gets past the window to its sub-components. What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Sub fixUIIn(ByRef comp As System.ComponentModel.Component, ByVal style As SByte)
    Debug.WriteLine(comp)
    If TypeOf comp Is System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl Then
        Dim c As System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl
        c = comp
        c.BackColor = getColor(style, PART_BACK)
        c.ForeColor = getColor(style, PART_TEXT)
        If ((comp.Container IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (comp.Container.Components IsNot Nothing)) Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To comp.Container.Components.Count() Step 1
                fixUIIn(comp.Container.Components.Item(i), style)
            Next
        End If
        comp = c
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you start with a Component rather than a Control but if you can start with a Control (such as a form) you can

try

```
Public Sub fixUIIn(ByRef comp As System.Windows.Forms.Control ByVal style As SByte)
    Debug.WriteLine(comp)
     comp.BackColor = getColor(style, PART_BACK)
     comp.ForeColor = getColor(style, PART_TEXT)

        If (comp.Controls IsNot Nothing) Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To comp.Controls.Count() 
                fixUIIn(comp.Controls.Item(i), style)
            Next
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks... I'll implement it once I get the Visual Studio GUI Builder to not fail